# IE10 event :(change) with confirm does not reset value to previous value

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, knockout.js

I have a problem with Internet Explorer (v 10 for now) I have 2 radio button yes/no with a confirm box, if the user click on Cancel, the value should go back to original value

Ex: yes is default value. user click no, popup show - user cancel should go back to yes.
Problem... the value does not change it's staying on No

My code work fine on FireFox and GoogleChrome

See jsFiddle (You must open it in IE10 I think...)

```
enter code here
```

https://jsfiddle.net/grosjambon/nxy0g1cg/

Please comment if jsfiddle does not work

**EDIT1**

Found something on here which work but have a little problems. When I try to bind multiple parameter to the function in the way Knockout is doing in the Click Binding, when the "person" confirm to change the value, the value is not updated in the radio button (both radio have nothing inside them)

HTML

```
<input class="radio-inline" type="radio" data-bind="click: function(data,event){confirmCheck2(lang('Options1'),false, '1Group0', data, event)}, checked: IsSomething,checkedValue: true" />
 <input class="radio-inline" type="radio" data-bind="click: function(data,event){confirmCheck2(lang('Options1'),true, '1Group0', data, event)}, checked: IsSomething,checkedValue: false" />
```

ViewModel(Knockout) Method that have problems with Ok confirm (both radio are empty)

```
 m.confirmCheck2 = function (propertyName, inputValue, stepName, data, event) {
                console.log(event);
                if (!confirm("Are you sure?")) {
                    event.stopImmediatePropagation();            
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
```

Method that work but does not have extra property

html

```
 <input class="radio-inline" type="radio" data-bind="click: confirmCheck, checked: IsITARAndCGP,checkedValue: true" />
```

viewmodel

```
m.confirmCheck = function (data, event) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(event);
                if (!confirm("Are you sure?")) {
                    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
```

**EDIT 2** So in between the reply I found a solution using the old answer of Roy. P.S If we complicate the problems : So I have multiple property m.Property1
m.Property2, m.Property3. When 1 is True all other are false, if the True Property goes False everything is false. Only 1 value can be true.

So, with the previous answer of RoyJ when you change a value, it will trigger the subscribe on each property that has the Confirm Popup because all 3 property trigger the same confirm.

```
    var showPopup = true; 
    m.Property1.subscribe(function () {
                var inputValue = m.Property1();
                if (showPopup) {
                    if (confirm(f.lang("Message"))) {
                        showPopup = false;//Disable showPopup because we set value inside resetValueFunction
                        resetValueWithCondition("Property1"), inputValue);
                    } else { // if cancel
                        showPopup = false;
                        m.Property1(!inputValue);
                        return true;//Exit code
                    }
                }
                showPopup = false;//Disable showPopup because we set value inside resetValueFunction
                resetValueWithCondition("Property2", inputValue);
                showPopup = true;

            });
            m.Property2.subscribe(function () {
                var inputValue = m.Property2();
                if (showPopup) {
                    if (confirm(f.lang("Message"))) {
                        showPopup = false;//Disable showPopup because we set value inside resetValueFunction
                        resetValueWithCondition("Property2", inputValue);
                    } else { // if cancel
                        showPopup = false;
                        m.Property2(!inputValue);
                        return true;//Exit code
                    }
                }

                showPopup = true;

            });
```

Function resetValueWithCondition

```
function resetValueWithCondition(propertyName,inputValue) {
                if (!m.Property1() && !m.Property2()) {//In this If I hide every field in my form and set Property 1 and Property2.... to false.
                    //m.Step1Visiblity(false);  
                    resetFormValueAfterStepPosition('1Group0');//Reset all form field      
                    setPropertyValue(false, false);//Here is simply m.Property1(false) etc...
                } else {
                    resetFormValueAfterStepPosition('1Group0');//Reset all form field
                    if (inputValue == true) {//Only perform this method if Property goes to True, otherwise don't execute (otherwise it trigger the confirm box multiple time when I Set Propertyvalue
                        m.visibilityLogic(propertyName);//Set PropertyValue to either true,false or false,true if is it property1 or property2
                    }

                }

            }
```

Comment: Is that the wrong fiddle, becuase it has nothing to do with your question

Comment: Should be good now? I edited the one Linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're paying too much attention to the form and not enough to your model. Instead of fiddling with events related to the radio buttons, work with your observables. In this case, you need a layer between your data item and the front end to check for the confirm.

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this,
    savedHS01 = ko.observable(true);

  self.HS01 = ko.computed({
    read: savedHS01,
    write: function(newValue) {
      if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
        savedHS01(newValue);
      }
      self.HS01.notifySubscribers();
    }
  });
  self.HS02 = ko.observable();
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input class="radio-inline" type="radio" data-bind="checked: HS01, checkedValue:true" />
  <span class="form-control-inline">yes</span>

  <input class="radio-inline" type="radio" data-bind="checked: HS01, checkedValue:false" />
  <span class="form-control-inline">no</span>
  <br/>Hs01:
  <input data-bind="value: HS01" />
  <br/>ShouldBe:
  <input data-bind="value: HS02" />
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Roy, Work fine when I click on No, but the confirm box does not show if I Click No --> Ok, then click Yes (Confirm box should pop). (Because !inputvalue of true = false. and If I edit the code it enter infinite loop on cancel event

Comment: I thought you only wanted to confirm on change from Yes to No. You'll need to use something like Protected Observables. http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html

Comment: I've updated the example code to behave more like a protected observable: the exposed observable is a writable computed that waits for confirmation to write to the "real" observable.

Comment: Hi roy, see edit2, I worked  on your old answer to make something work. with the not simplified problems (see edit2)... I will try the updated answer to see if its work

Comment: The usual way of handling a radio-group situation is to have a `selectedItem` that indicates which of the possible properties is selected. The true-false value for each of the items can be computed from `selectedItem == this`.

Comment: hmm, not sure to see how it would work. Here is a fiddle with updated code to show what im kinda doing https://jsfiddle.net/8tbw7jgo/ tell me if the jsfiddle work

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8tbw7jgo/2/
I made a selectedProperty value. When a property becomes true, it gets that property. And when it changes, each property checks to see whether it needs to become false.

Comment: Cool! last question, would that be the correct/best way to handle my visibility logic? https://jsfiddle.net/8tbw7jgo/15/ see this modified jsfiddle.

Comment: Red visibility is exactly Property1, and green visibility is exactly property2. You don't need to have new variables for them. https://jsfiddle.net/8tbw7jgo/16/

Comment: Yes but this is a simplified solution of what I'm currently doing. I have Property1 Show Field 1 and 2, Property 2 show Field 2 and 3, Property3 show Field 3,Property4 show Field 1. So I have something called setFieldVisibility(field1,field2,field3) and in Html I would have for Field1 data-bind:Visible : Field1Visibility

Comment: They should be computeds, not separate variables. Only use separate variables for things that are independent.

Comment: Oh! did not knew about this one... so it should be like that? https://jsfiddle.net/8tbw7jgo/17/